# Xcode Can't Find Editor in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, cs50

I am currently working on CS50's iOS track and am on the Pokedex assignment. I need to find the editor in the storyboard in Xcode, but my Xcode interface for the storyboard looks nothing like what's shown in the videos. Can someone explain how to get to the editor for labels and other elements in my storyboard?

[image: Storyboard without element editor]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the **assistant editor**, then

1. select your Viewcontroller in the storyboard
2. in the top right corner click on the second button from the right (the one with all the lines) and select assistant editor from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the **Attributes Inspector**. Just press the icon at the top-right to expand it.

[image]

Comment: This icon didn't show up for me so I found it at view -> inspectors -> attributes inspector.

Comment: Yeah, depends on the operating system (before Big Sur it looks different)